# PDF using embedded subset font for form fields

Tags: pdf, fonts, subset, pdf-form

Generally PDF permits the embedding of subsets of fonts. But e.g. these two sources ([1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/designerHelp/index.htm?content=000163.html) ; [2](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/embed-fonts-in-a-form-q302105.aspx)) declare using a embedded subset of a (non base 14) font is not possible within fillable form fields - and one has to fully embed the font.

**1) Isn't there any workaround for using a embedded subset of for instance courier new for form fields?**

2) Is there maybe a solution to end up with a embedded *custom* font that came with the individual subset of e.g. courier new?

Comment: The PDF specification does not stop you from using a version of a font for fillable form fields which does not contain the full set of glyphs usually found in that font. PDF building tools, on the other hand, probably do not support cutting down a font as you desire. But you can always create a restricted version of a font using some font editor and embed that font version.

Comment: If the character d does exist in the subset you will not be able to enter it